# How long does it take for space dust to stop irradiating energy?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, space, infrared-radiation

I heard that space dust is detectable because it irradiates on the infrared part of the spectrum? Does this happen forever? Won't it stop after some millions of years? Does it have to irradiate until it reaches 0 Kelvin? How long does it take to do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium#Heating_mechanisms mentions a number of mechanism that are  heating these clouds, which means that they will stay warm as long as one or several of these heating mechanisms are active. Without the heating the clouds will be at the temperature of the CMB.

Comment: BTW space dust is not only detectable by its emission, but also by its absorption of background, and its reflection when close enough to powerful sources.